# Update options from a dropdown list

Tags: jquery, django

I have a Dorpdownlist with a lot of options. So I want to filter these options with a text.

```
$("input.form-control").change(function () {
    var value = $('.form-control').val();

    //now I need to remove the options witch not contains the value in the text.

});


<select id="id_customer" name="customer">
    <option value="1">Max Musterman </option>
    <option value="2">Heidi Mustermann </option>
</select>
```

maybe the removed options have to added again, if the value changes.
This is only my first step with jquery. If you have a solution with Django, Ajax or something else, it's also fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.filter()`

```
$("input.form-control").change(function () {
    var value = $('.form-control').val();

    $('#id_customer option').filter(function(){
       return $(this).text() != value;
    }).remove();

});
```

Comment: Probably best to get rid of the trailing spaces from the `option`'s texts as they will break the text comparison.

Comment: Is there a way with "contain"? So i have to type the hole name find a option. How to show removed options again?

Comment: @spitzbuaamy you can use `indexOf` to check if it contains some string.

Comment: like `$(this).text().indexOf(value) > 0`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your way of Contains work fine. But you should write ">=" instead of ">".